# ForkJoin() issue on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Hello I am currently working on an UI and I need to print for each 'digId' a value that I retrieved in an unique JSON response. 
In the case below, I have 3 incidents and I did a fork to have access to the 3 JSON response.

```
digId='4149';                                               
digId2='4719';
digId3='4309';

ngOnInit(): void {

const parallel$ = Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('http://ninjaopsapi?tablename=REF_OPS_ALARM&babylonref=' + this.digId),
      this.http.get('http://ninjaopsapi?tablename=REF_OPS_ALARM&babylonref=' + this.digId2),
        this.http.get('http://ninjaopsapi?tablename=REF_OPS_ALARM&babylonref=' + this.digId3)
    );

    parallel$.subscribe( data => {
    this.alarms = data, console.log(data);

  }) 

}
```

My goal is to print the element circled in blue for example:  [Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbKtC.png)

But with this code below in my html, I retrieve the element [0] for the three incidents and I can't put an additionnal [0] to select only one.

```
<div *ngFor= "let alarm of alarms">

                <div [(ngModel)]="digId" ngDefaultControl>

                      <div>{{alarm[0].alertMessage}}</div>
                 </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to print the first element of the first element in an array when the .subscribe is done with a "forkJoin()" ?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I only changed `{{alarm[0][0].alertMessage}}` by  `{{alarms[0][0].alertMessage}}` and delete the loop `*ngFor="let alarm of alarms`
and it works well ! Thank you

Comment: If you provide a small stackblitz repro with mock data it'd be easier to help you out

Comment: Isn't it just `<div>{{alarm.alertMessage}}</div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do

```
parallel$.subscribe( data => {
    this.alarms = data.map(x => x[0]);
});
```

---

```
<div>{{alarm.alertMessage}}</div>
```

Comment: Great! or use one more *ngFor and *ngIf! =)